# "~/.cassandra" folder - what is it used for?

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

I want to create an automated installation script which includes Cassandra. I had some trouble before which I solved before by deleting "~/.cassandra". Is it safe to delete it automatically every time I run the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it safe to delete it automatically every time I run the script?

Safe?  Sure, but probably not a good idea.

The `.cassandra` directory holds command history for your `cqlsh`, `cli`, and `nodetool` sessions.  It is also the default location for the `.cqlshrc` file, which (if created) [allows you to persist various settings](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/cqlsh.html?scroll=refCqlsh__cqlshUsingCqlshrc) for your `cqlsh` sessions (username, default keyspace, timestamp format, etc...).

So while I don't think you'll hurt anything by deleting it, I wouldn't do it.

> I had some trouble before which I solved before by deleting "~/.cassandra".

There was probably something goofy in your `cqlsh` history at one point, and deleting the entire folder prevented it from crashing on a parsing error (if I had to guess).

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the .whatever folders and files [are "hidden" by convention and are typically used for storing shell history and things like that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory). Sometimes they can be used to store configuration, but that is on a per-application basis.

The .cassandra folder is not [mentioned in the documentation,](https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/GettingStarted) so I suspect you are safe to delete it as long as you don't mind losing the shell history.

I don't know specifically about Cassandra, but I would suspect it is used for shell history.  You could always look into it and see.